# integer[] column with WHERE ANY operator in JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I work on following table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "skill_ids", columnDefinition = "integer[]")
    @Type(type = "com.example.utils.IntegerArrayUserType")
    private List<Integer> skillIds;

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

The column `skill_ids` as you can see is array of integers. It can contains different number of ids. I would like to fetch all `Employee` entities which `skillIds` contains all ids provided in array received from application front-end. I would like to use `CriteriaBuilder` and `Specification.toPredicate` method and I wrote something like this:

```
public Specification<Employee> attributeListVsList(List<Integer> skillIds) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Expression<List<Integer>> attributeValuesList = root.get("skillIds");
        return builder.or(attributeValuesList.in(skillIds));
    }
}
```

Above method produces obviously `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer`.How can I implement `Specification.toPredicate` method to get `Employee` entities in a proper way? In pure SQL I can fetch all demanded rows that way (for `skillIds` = [1, 2] for instance):

```
SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE 1 = ANY (skill_ids) AND
          2 = ANY (skill_ids);
```

However I have to use `CriteriaBuilder` because there are some additional specifications using this approach.

Comment: you can't save an array to the database unless you serialize it. Which would make it a blob

Comment: `skillIds` array is being saved to the database without issue. There is serialization but I am wondering how fetch specific rows from the DB.

Comment: Use `JOINS` to do that.

Comment: @Antoniossss you mean: `Join join = root.join("skillIds");` in `toPredicate`? How can I use this join?

Comment: exacly like you did `join("xxx").get("propname")` and you know the drill (simple equals predicate).

Comment: wait but is it actual join ???...... I would reorganize model to use joins.

Comment: In fact this is no actual join. `skillIds` is column in table which type is just `integer[]`... I know how it looks, it wasn't my decision...

Comment: I never faced that issue before. As it uses native type, you may need to use native query as well for that. You might however end up with some sort of custom dialect

Comment: Never did that (never had to) either.  Maybe you should ask is there any way to override query build in such way that it would create specific query when using `equality` or `in` operator on 2 particular argument types, in this case it would be `integer[]` and `integer`

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you will have to use your custom `Criterion`. Here you have an example how to implement your own criterions.

http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2013/01/creating-new-criterion.html

This way you will be able to construct required query. Be adviced that this will be RDBMS dependant.

Comment: In the JPA API? Criterion? Really

Comment: I'm afraid I can't user Criterion in JPA API as @BillyFrost has commented